# How to make a progressbar in tkinter and How to connect it to a function

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a software in tkinter python 3.3.2. I want my program to work in this way:

1. When I import tha data (txt file) I want my program shows a progressbar where indicates the software is reading the data
2. When the software reads the data and apply the "function", I want the software shows a new progressbar where indicates the software is applying the function on the data
3. Then the software apply the function, it exports a txt file with the results, so I want the software shows a new progressbar where indicates the software is exporting the new txt file with the results.

I want my program show the progressbar when is reading the data, when is applying the function, and when exports a new txt file with results.

Any ideas?

Help please!!!

Answer (score 1):

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm says that:

"Another common use for this widget is to implement various kinds of custom widgets. For example, you can use a canvas as a completion bar, by drawing and updating a rectangle on the canvas."